# How to list record as json for outer join active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

i created active record through outer join and rendering json. when i render this i'm not getting outer joined table datas. how to fetch it

```
@recent_details = Property
  .includes(:space_amenities,:event_suitabilities,:purpose_suitabilities,:venue_categories)
  .where(id: params[:id])
render json: @recent_details
```

this is how i rendered index.jbuiler.json form

```
json.recent_details @recent_details
```

here i got all details from properties table except the outer join tables. how to get the outer joined table results here

Comment: try render json: Property.includes(:space_amenities,:event_suitabilities,:purpose_suitabilities,:venue_categories).where(id: params[:id]).to_json

Comment: i tried like this. but this time i'm getting properties details plus only one join table details which is the last one(purpose_suitabilities).  Any idea how to add all

Comment: ' respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @recent_details.to_json(include: :space_amenities,:event_suitabilities,include: :purpose_suitabilities) }
end`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call something like `@recent_details.frist.space_amenities` to get the data, the `includes` actually query the data for you, but it won't merge all data together. it's just when you call `@recent_details.first.space_amenities`, the database will not query again, because `includes` queried for you already. in your case you need to specify what columns you want to add to your json result. for example:

```
json.recent_details @recent_details do |rd|
  json.space_amenities rd.space_amenities
end
```

this will not have n+1 query problem

if you take out `includes(:space_amenities,:event_suitabilities,:purpose_suitabilities,:venue_categories)`, the same code will have n+1 query problem, you will see in your server log that multiple sql query are made for each `recent_detail`